# No XAML Hot Reload for WinUI projects in either VS2019 or VS2022

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2019, hot-reload, winui-3, visual-studio-2022

I've tried with both Visual Studio 2019 (`16.11.5`) and Visual Studio 2022 (`17.0.0 P5`), but am unable to get XAML Hot Reload working for WinUI projects (both UWP and Desktop types).

WPF project's are unaffected and XAML Hot Reload continues to work.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

I'm running Windows 10 20H2 and have the extension Windows App SDK (Experimental) 1.0.0.50489432 installed, with Hot Reload enabled across all frameworks:

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I just tested this with Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.2.6 and Windows App SDK 1.1.1. I can make a change in the XAML and see the effects in the application immediately (without having to save the XAML document).